# jQuery/CSS - Loading images from right to left using Waypoint

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I have the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98y5j9c8/2/), here is the code:-

**HTML**

```
<div class="spacer"><h1 style="color: #FFFFFF;">SCROLL DOWN</h1></div>
<div class="wrapper">
     <span class="pink-curve"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-2">
     <span class="pink-curve-2"></span>
</div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;  
    height: 949px;
}
.wrapper-2 {
    position: relative;  
    height: 949px;
}
.spacer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  background: black;
}
.pink-curve {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/pink-curve.png);
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 72px;
    top: 206px;
}

.pink-curve-2 {
    background: url(http://planetbounce.m360.co.uk/wp-content/themes/planetbounce/assets/img/pink-curve-2.png);
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 72px;
    top: 206px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(function() {
    var curve1 = jQuery('.pink-curve');
       curve1.waypoint(function(direction) {
            curve1.css({"height" : "30px", "width" : "80px"});
         }, {
           offset: '70%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "80px", "width" : "80px"});
         }, {
           offset: '68%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "100px", "width" : "80px"});
         }, {
           offset: '66%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "165px", "width" : "100px"});
         }, {
           offset: '64%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "200px", "width" : "180px"});
         }, {
           offset: '62%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "240px", "width" : "180px"});
         }, {
           offset: '60%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "300px", "width" : "180px"});
         }, {
           offset: '58%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "300px", "width" : "220px"});
         }, {
           offset: '56%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "270px"});
         }, {
           offset: '54%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "320px"});
         }, {
           offset: '52%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "370px"});
         }, {
           offset: '50%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "430px"});
         }, {
           offset: '48%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "480px"});
         }, {
           offset: '46%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "520px"});
         }, {
           offset: '44%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "570px"});
         }, {
           offset: '42%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "620px"});
         }, {
           offset: '40%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "670px"});
         }, {
           offset: '38%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "720px"});
         }, {
           offset: '36%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "770px"});
         }, {
           offset: '34%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "820px"});
         }, {
           offset: '32%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "870px"});
         }, {
           offset: '30%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "905px"});
         }, {
           offset: '28%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "365px", "width" : "949px"});
         }, {
           offset: '26%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "405px", "width" : "949px"});
         }, {
           offset: '24%'
         });
       curve1.waypoint(function() {
            curve1.css({"height" : "436px", "width" : "949px"});
         }, {
           offset: '22%'
         });
   var curve2 = jQuery('.pink-curve-2');
   curve2.waypoint(function(direction) {
        curve2.css({"height" : "30px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '70%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "80px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '68%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "100px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '66%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "165px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '64%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "200px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '62%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "240px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '60%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "300px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '58%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "300px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '56%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '54%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '52%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '50%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '48%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '46%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '44%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '42%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '40%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '38%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '36%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '34%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '32%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '30%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "330px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '28%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "365px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '26%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "405px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '24%'
     });
   curve2.waypoint(function() {
        curve2.css({"height" : "426px", "width" : "942px"});
     }, {
       offset: '22%'
     });
   // 942 -  426
    });
```

The first example works fine (`.pink-curve`) but for the second example (`.pink-curve-2`) it doesn't work properly as the image is the opposite way around. The image needs to somehow load or appear from right to left.

The only way I can think of is overlaying a div over the top but the problem I have is that I am using a pattern background underneath so this wouldn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/98y5j9c8/4/ is that what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not @makshh - the image position in that example is moving from left to right. It needs to work like the first example, so the image is always in the same place but the image starts to appear from right to left. Basically the opposite of the first example.